# how to use Querybuilder in symfony 3.4 with mongodb doctrine?i have issue i try but this is not give data. this is code and display page

Tags: mongodb, symfony, query-builder

this is my code:

```
$role_id = $this->get('session')->get('role_id');
$em = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()->getRepository('AdminBundle:Rolemaster');
$role = $em->createQueryBuilder()->field('rolename')->notEqual('admin')->getQuery()->execute();
    var_dump($role);exit; `
```

this is the image of output:

[Outputimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U1p8.png)

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior as executing a query for Doctrine MongoDB query builder, returns a cursor for you to iterate over the results. You can refer to the documentation [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/query-builder-api.html#executing-queries).

If you want to get the result as an array you have to use `toArray()` on the cursor:

```
$role = $em->createQueryBuilder()
           ->field('rolename')
           ->notEqual('admin')
           ->getQuery()->execute()->toArray();
```